# Disable post-new.php (default Post type)?

Tags: customization

I have no need for the post-new.php, the default post type for some of my User Roles. I have tried to disable post-new.php by adding it to Adminimize Custom field. No success yet. I am able to remove the menu entry, so the only thing that's left is that you still can reach the URL itself.
I want the post-new.php and post-new.php?post_type=post to be disabled, but everything else (like post-new.php?post_type=custom) to be functional.

I have tried everything I have found when googling.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: You're thinking about this the wrong way. You should be looking at capabilities. Give your custom post type custom capabilities then just remove the post related capabilities from the roles that don't need them

Comment: How do I give the custom post type custom capabilities?